# Numb Tingeling in Big Toes

Tags: injury, fat, walking, overtraining, numbness

Me: Overweight 30 year old male.

This year has been a particularly inactive year* leading me to grow increasingly interested in getting into shape. Because of this, and other reasons, this lead me to start a new hard labor job.

this puts me on my feet 12 hours a day, doing physical labor, with a lot of walking. And shortly after this started my big toes have become constantly tingeing and numb feeling when pressure is applied to them.

Normally, my first thought would be diabetes, or some other overweight disease, but I know of none that are exasperated by extreme exercise. If it matters, prior to this job I did everything barefoot.

**My question**: Is this normal? Will bruised feet feel like this? Will it go away? Or is this likely a more serious condition.

- This year was an anomaly.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a medical forum. Even if it was, how could we possibly diagnose you over the internet? Please go see your doctor.

Answer (score 2):

Speaking as a runner, it could be as simple as your shoes being too small and/or tied too tight. Feet swell throughout the day, so either of those will make uncomfortable feel unbearable.